# Laravel public directory and middleware

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.4

I have a page builder that I bought from [Envato](https://envato.com/) and according to it's installation notes

> Installing the HTML Builder is simply a matter uploading the "builder" folder to a server/hosting account. Once uploaded, point your browser to builder's directory and the builder will work. 
>   For example: www.yoursite.com/builder

So I've uploaded it to public/page-builder directory and it's accessible through `mysite.com/page-builder` and I didn't add any route in the routes file. Now I want it to be only accessible by the admin. How do I do this?

Comment: @SapneshNaik okay I also found that in existing questions here in stackoverflow. It works but the next problem is the css and js files are also located in the same folder. And laravel can't find them